# If name is X insert Y phone number from Z worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a simple macro or VBA that will insert a phone number in column Y for value of someones name in Column X from a directory worksheet.

So for example, worksheet 1 (directory) has names of individuals and phone numbers:

```
John Smith 123 456 789
Joe Garden 555 555 555
Jill Spill 999 999 999
```

When creating a new worksheet 2, when I put John Smith in Column A, I want it to automatically populate 123 456 789 in Column B.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: on worksheet 1 is the name in one column and the phone number in another column? if so you don't need a macro, you can use a formula on worksheet 2, if this is the case let me know and i can provide you with the formula...

Comment: You can use the `worksheet_change` event for this, or a formula using VLOOKUP

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak yes, they are in separate columns. Some may have more than one number listed too if that is a possibility for example in the directory - Column A = name, Column B = Phone number, Column C = Phone #2 (if available)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if there's anything that I missed. Be sure to change **Sheet4** to the name of the sheet that has the phone # list.

```
Sub Macro12()
   Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet4!C[-1]:C,2,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```